# How can I share only a small portion of my screen/display?

Tags: windows-7, screen-sharing

Does anyone know how to share **only** a portion of your display when screen sharing (via something like Remote Desktop or VNC)?

Say I have a program running (in Windows 7), and I want to show JUST the top half of the GUI for *that* program. I have not found any screen-sharing software that can accomplish this. The closest I've seen is [Skype](http://www.skype.com/intl/en-us/home), which can share the whole GUI window excluding the rest of your desktop.

I have tried:

- [Join.me](https://join.me/)
- [Quick Screen Share](http://quickscreenshare.com/)
- [Live Look](http://www.showscreen.com/)

If there's not a program to support this, is there some workaround I could do?

Comment: mention those numerous solutions that you've tried

Comment: Related: https://superuser.com/questions/1640021/video-conferencing-with-a-wide-display-how-may-i-share-a-subset-of-my-entire-de

Answer (score 1):

Teamviewer can share only an application, as for part of said application I do not think it will do just that.  But it can share only your powerpoint or other application if that is what you are after.

[Teamviewer Meetings](http://www.teamviewer.com/en/products/online-meeting.aspx)

Comment: As a strong user of Teamviewer, I would also strongly recommend it.

Answer (score 1):

[SeeVogh](https://seevogh.com/welcome/) is primarily a video conferencing system, but it's screen sharing feature, called Deskshare, allows you to draw a box on the screen and it will share what appears in that box. The red box in the image below shows the feature:

[image: The red box is the Deskshare feature]

Answer (score -1):

As of 2017 there is a free, lightweight solution for selecting a part of your screen called [Screenleap](http://www.screenleap.com/). However, the free version is limited to 1 hour of use per day (2 if you are an .edu user).